# Approximate $(0.99)^{300}$ without calculator

Tags: calculus

> Approximate $(0.99)^{300}$ without calculator.

This question is in my textbook but i don't know how to approximate without calculator. How can i evaluate without calculator? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you claiming that the textbook in which this appears as an exercise provides **no** information about how to do it?

Comment: Hint: you can see it as $(1-0.01)^300$ and $0.01 \ll 1$.

Comment: @Delta-u I'm pretty sure that approximation ($(1+x)^r\sim1+rx$) fails due to how large $300$ is.

Comment: Do you know logarithms?

Comment: @RushabhMehta indeed :-). But you can see it as $\exp(300 \ln(1-\varepsilon))$. My comment was only to identify what is the small parameter in my opinion.

Comment: I approximate it as $1$.

Comment: @TheCount So, if I roll a 100 sided dice 300 times, there's a 100% chance I won't get any 1s?

Comment: My approximation is 100. You didn't say how good the approximation has to be.

Comment: There are no explanatory examples in text book. We have a prof that doesnt like explain a lot. In textbook there are some rules with ln and e approximation.

Comment: Hint: $\log(1-x) \simeq -x -x^2/2$ for small $x$. Can you use that?

Comment: @AlexanderGruber maybe we are using different definitions of the word "approximate" and of the concept of humor.

Comment: @TheCount My point was that there is really only a <5% chance, but you are correct on the second point-- moderators have no concept of humor

Comment: @AlexanderGruber and my point was that the question was not stated well at first. and i know all about moderator humor, but thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$300 \ln (1-1/100) \approx 300 (-1/100-1/20000) \approx -3$$

$$e^{-3} = (3-(3-e))^{-3} \approx \frac{1}{27} \left(1+(3-e)\right)=\frac{4-e}{27}=0.0475...$$

$$0.99^{300}=0.0490...$$

As for "without calculator", using $e=2.718...$ is enough. If you remember how to divide by hand.

Answer (score 13):

Remark that we can write:
$$
(0.99)^{300}
=
(1-0.01)^{300}
=
\left( 1 + \frac{-3}{300} \right)^{300}
$$

Now, recalling that we have:
$$
e^x = \lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} 
\left( 1 + \frac{x}{n} \right)^{n}
$$

We conclude that we can approximate $(0.99)^{300}$ as $e^{-3}$.

Comment: This is nice, I didn't notice the significance of $300$

Comment: Basically, if $n$ is large, then the approximation is good. 300 is "pretty big", so the approximation is "pretty good".

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really saved my time. This method is very helpful.

Comment: I assume this is what the textbook was going for; it seems like a way to introduce students to the idea of $e$.

Comment: @ishakbayrak If you think this answers your question, you can click the check mark to mark this answer as "accepted".